# The right way of starting Behat feature/story

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, bdd, behat

I'm starting the BDD and after some readings I found out it goes well with DDD.

Now I have this domain, where a `Institution` have `Places`, which are added to the `Institution` by `Assignee` which is an `User` assigned as manager of organization.

I still can't wrap my head around how it should be, but the feature sounds like: **As an assignee of institution I must be able to add places to the organization**

The code I'm thinking about (sorry for the code-first approach) would look like this:

```
if ($institution->isAssignee($user)) {
    $institution->addPlace(/* properties*/);
}
```

Now how should I write the feature and its scenarios? Should I leave the **as an assignee** part and leave it? OR should there be a multiple scenarios? How would the scenario look like?

**EDIT:**

So I left the user permission check for now and started first feature followed by specifications of implementation. The code could be found [here](https://github.com/andrius-kulbis/bdd-ddd).

Isn't this feature to simple? Of course its the core of what the my domain does, but I even did not mentioned a case in my feature where the place with same location could not be added, but I have done this in the `InstitutionSpec`?

Moving forward: if i would like to edit `Place` of an institution, what would be a better approach:

```
$place = $institution->getPlace($placeId);
$place->editWhatever(/***/);
```

OR

```
$institution->editWhateverInPlace($placeId, /** edits **/);
```

Answer (score 0):

The check that a user have the permission to add a place to a `Institution` seems like another's `bounded context`(`BC`) problem like `Authorisation`. This check could be done in a `Anticoruption layer` in the `Application layer` outside the `Institution aggregate` by querying the `Authorisation BC` to create an `Assignee` from a user that have the role of `"assignee"`.

In this BC there is just an `Assignee`, possible implemented ad a `Value object` that have a `UserId` and possible a `name`.

P.S. Your `BDD`  tests should be split by `BC` and furthermore by `Aggregate`.

Comment: Figuring out whether or not a user is an assignee for a given institution is probably not as easy as role checking. I'm usually all for a supporting Identity & Access BC, but here the supporting context would need to introduce an additionnal set of abstractions such as playing a role in a specific context or for a specific target. It may be easier to model the association directly in the BC that needs it.

Answer (score 0):

I read your [scenarios](https://github.com/andrius-kulbis/bdd-ddd/blob/master/features/add-place.feature), I think that you mix to scenarios in one in [Can't add place with same location](https://github.com/andrius-kulbis/bdd-ddd/blob/master/features/add-place.feature#L11)

Usually, at start most developers thinking of reuse all steps. You simply hidded what should this scenario show - block adding new place with same coordinations. Simply first step should be (in my opinion):

```
Given an institution named "Test institution" with places:
| name       | coordination  |
| Test Place | 54.222,24.333 |
```

Then polishing your scenarios like that, help you find you naming way better, showing problems.

As you are asking: `Isn't this feature to simple?` - if each scenario is correctly splitted per functionality - then NO - you are design you code by behavioral. IF this is only what you need then OK, but you should also think about boundary conditions of functionality - add next scenarios.

About last part, with edit place - think about SOLID.
I hear good example of that :D

What you prefer:

- got to cage -> catch lion -> grab stomach by jaw -> put food inside -> put stomach back -> leave

OR

- go to cage -> throw food to lion -> leave ?

First option break [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) that is basic of SOLID, as you try to grab 'stomach' of institution.

I think, in you context, second option is better.